# Как лучше удалять записи по истечении даты

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база, где хранятся записи, мне нужно, что бы по истечении даты, записи удалялась.

Вот сам запрос:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM reestrs WHERE date_check < now();";
```

Как сделать так, что бы он автоматически выполнялся раз в какое то время?

Comment: написать скрипт, который будет это делать и запускать эту задачу по крону в нужное время

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая вещь, как **CRON**

**Cron** - классический демон-планировщик задач в UNIX-подобных операционных системах, использующийся для периодического выполнения заданий в определённое время.

C помощью него вы сможете делать все что угодно, удалять что-то из базы или добавлять, делать вещи не связанные с базой, какой-либо парсинг данных откуда-либо и прочие любые угодные душе вещи.

Чтобы было более понятно, в `windows` для каких либо простых задач используется `Стандартные->Служебные->планировщик заданий`.

Хотя конкретно для **веб** задач **в винде** можно взять в интернете программу `cron` для `windows`.

Информации по крону много, её стоит изучить

[ссылка1](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/cron.php)

[ссылка2](https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/cron/)

[ссылка3](https://100.org.ua/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-cron-crontab-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5/)

На хостингах, как правило, всегда имеется планировщик с удобным интерфейсом и  прикрепить задачу или скрипт будет просто.