# PHP, функция sleep, нагрузка на процессор

Tags: php

Вопрос простой: если программа должна выполнять операцию раз в сутки например,
то нужно применить функцию sleep:

```
   sleep(86400);
```

насколько сильно эта операция загрузит компьютер?

Comment: Проще запустить и посмотреть при помощи top, например...

Comment: нужно использовать планировщик, а не sleep

Comment: а для php есть планировщики?

Comment: @heff а причем тут непосредственно PHP?

Comment: лучше sleep не использовать, как указал Алексей выше, это поможет избежать утечек памяти, как минимум. Плюс, кто вам гарантирует, что уснувший скрипт никто не прибьёт за такое-то длинное время?

Comment: Гуглить по слову `cron`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как лучше удалять записи по истечении даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466408/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b)

Comment: + https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=cron