# Автоматический запуск скрипта без загрузки сайта

Tags: php, mysql, хостинг

Предположим я создал на сервере файл (PHP), который будет на другом сайте собирать данные. Как сделать так, чтобы файл автоматически заходил на тот сайт и сам собирал данные?

Да, файл находится на сервере провайдера

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron+php

Comment: + ссылки на чтиво есть тут [Как лучше удалять записи по истечении даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466413/191482)